# Function from wedge sum of three circles to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to construct three functions from the bouquet of three circles to $S^1$ to create a surjective homomorphism from the fundamental group of the bouquet to $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

But, I'm unsure how to even construct such a $f: (S_1\vee S_1\vee S_1) \to S_1$. My first thought is to just define three projections, $f_1, f_2, f_3$. I.e., for each $f_i$, if a point is in the $i$th circle, it gets sent to that point in $S^1$, otherwise it gets sent to $1\in S^1$. Then, by the gluing lemma I can combine these functions into one continuous function, and then use that each circle has the fundamental group of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then, for any loop
$$
[g]\in\pi_1(S_1\vee S_1\vee S_1),$$
the coordinate it gets sent to in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ would be $(n_1, n_2, n_3)$, where $n_i$ is the winding number of the restriction of $g$ to just the $i$th circle. This is clearly  surjective.

However, I have absolutely no clue how to formalize this at all. I'm unsure how to even represent a point in $S_1\vee S_1\vee S_1$. For $p\in S_1$, it's always represented as just $e^{\pi ix}$ for some real number $x$, or just $(x_1, x_2)$ such that $(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2 = 1$. But, I have no clue how to represent a point in the bouquet of three circles. And, if I don't know how to even represent a point in the domain, I can't construct a function. I also don't even know if I'm even taking the right approach.

Comment: Since you mentioned gluing lemma, you presumably have a way to define $S_1 \vee S_1 \vee S_1$ via some quotient of $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$.  That should give you a representation of points on bouquet of three circles.